# TensorFlow Combining Dense Layer with LSTM Cell

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorboard

How do i combine a Tensorflow Dense Layer, which is then followed by a LSTM!

Given a sequence of variable length, i want to backprop through both the layers, since i will be using this for RL.

How do i format my input sequence/ define my layers to be consistent with size requirements?